# Highcharts Color Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, highcharts, coffeescript

I'm just starting to play around with highcharts. I've found that when setting the color attribute it doesn't actually set that specific hex color - rather it only displays that exact hex color when you hover over the chart and it highlights. Highcharts seems to be "auto-dimming" the color so that when you hover over it it highlights and displays the specific hex color you list when creating the chart.

Is there a way to set the *actual* color that appears? It'd be nice to just be able to specific which hex color should appear initially and which hex color displays when it's highlighted, rather than it auto-dimming the color and highlighting to the hex color you specify:

```
$('#ageChart').highcharts({
        chart: {
          marginRight: 50,
          marginTop: 0,
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
          text: '',
          style: {
            fontSize: 10
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            size: 300,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Age Breakdown',
          data: [
            {
              name: "14-17",
              y: fourteenToSeventeen,
              color: "#E0DBBA"
            },
            {
              name: "18-24",
              y: eighteenToTwentyFour,
              color: "#8C8C8B"
            },
            {
              name: "25-34",
              y: twentyFiveToThirtyFour,
              color: "#BEE7E8"
            },
            {
              name: "35-44",
              y: thirtyFiveToFourtyFour,
              color: "#217C7E"
            },
            {
              name: "45-54",
              y: fourtyFiveToFiftyFour,
              color: "#687D68"
            },
            {
              name: "55+",
              y: fiftyFivePlus,
              color: "#634357"
            }
          ]
        }]
      })
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/1k9cytL3/
I've put some dummy values btw. Isn't the colors showing correctly?

Comment: So the colors "work" as in they show up as different colors. But the actual hex color that displays isn't what I put in. Only when you hover over the graph does it actually display the hex color you listed. So highcharts seems to be "auto-dimming" the color or something.

Comment: Basically has our designer up in arms that her colors aren't displaying correctly :)

Comment: I just verified the colors using Photoshop. The colors are being displayed correctly, but what is happening is that on hover state, the colors are being "brightened" by Highcharts. Check this fiddle where I've disabled this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/ae1xam4o/1/

Comment: That'll do it! Want to add that as an answer and I'll accept? Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: That would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are actually being displayed correctly. But on hover state, the colors get "brightened" by Highcharts.

This behavior can be turned off by specifying the brightness factor to 0 like so:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        ..
        ..

        series: [{
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Age Breakdown',

            //add this section
            states: {
                hover: {
                    brightness: 0   
                }
            },

            data: [
            ..
            ..
            ]
        }]

   })
```